# Best way to specialize function using enable_if for only some types

Tags: c++, c++14

I have this code that specializes the print function for two types, and reverts back to the base version for any other types.

My question is, is there a way to write this without having to type out the negative case for all the specialized versions in the enable_if of the base print function?

i.e. is there a way to remove all the `!std::is_same` and still have an unambiguous print function?

Any versions of C++ welcome, but one that works in c++14 would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, int>::value && !std::is_same<T, double>::value, int> = 42>
void print(T data)
{
    std::cout << "base:" << data << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, double>::value, int> = 42>
void print(T data)
{
    std::cout << "double:" << data << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value, int> = 42>
void print(T data)
{
    std::cout << "int:" << data << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo("foo");
    double bar = 1.2;
    int baz = 5;
    print(foo);
    print(bar);
    print(baz);
}
```

Comment: C++17 `if constexpr` would be the more readable IMO, but C++17. Maybe C++20 concepts, if you have appropriate concept for your conditions, but again, not C++14.

Answer (score 3):

For your use case, you can simply provide overloads for the `print` function as needed

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> 
void print(T data)
{
    std::cout << "base:" << data << std::endl;
}

void print(double data)
{
    std::cout << "double:" << data << std::endl;
}

void print(int data)
{
    std::cout << "int:" << data << std::endl;
}
```

However, if you have more complicated constraints on `T`, then you can't specialize `print` without explicitly providing the negation of the constraints in the "default" case.

If you have access to c++17, you can write this in a single function. The usual if-else logic means that the base case is only triggered if the "specializations" are not. This avoids having to specify the negations.

```
template<typename T> 
void print(T data)
{
 if constexpr(std::is_same<T, double>{})
   std::cout << "double:" << data << std::endl;
 else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>{})
   std::cout << "int:" << data << std::endl;
 else // if not same as int or double
   std::cout << "base:" << data << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: apologies, I trivialised my example, I am doing something much more complicated in the is_same in my real example so the above isn't an option.

Comment: @Salgar edited the answer. It's c++17, but satisfies your requirements, even if the enable_if constraints are more complicated.

Comment: Overload is generally better than specialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 agreed, but OP says their constraints are more complicated than just is_same, so just an overload wouldn't work.

Comment: Replacing in the example `std::is_same` by `std::is_integral`/`std::is_floating_point` would make the specialization not possible (as we don't want to duplicate overload for `float`/`double`/`long double`...).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, that's legit. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Btw, I wont suggest to OP to edit question in a way which invalidate existing answers. Maybe asking another one is better.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I deleted that comment. Also, updated answer.

Comment: In OP case, `if constexpr` can even be replaced by regular `if`. which might not be the case for real code.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid complementary conditions is to give an overload priority between overload:

```
template <std::size_t N> struct priority_overload : priority_overload<N - 1> {};
template <> struct priority_overload<0>  {}; // Least priority
```

and then

```
template<typename T>
void print(T data, priority_overload<0>) // fallback
{
    std::cout << "base:" << data << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<condition1<T>::value, int> = 42>
void print(T data, priority_overload<1>)
{
    std::cout << "cond1:" << data << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<condition2<T>::value, int> = 42>
void print(T data, priority_overload<2>)
{
    std::cout << "cond2:" << data << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print(T data)
{
    print(data, priority_overload<10>{});
    // Priority should be greater or equal to the one of possible overloads
}
```