# template function overload: enable_if for CRTP, compiler insists on selecting generic function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, crtp

This is a model case where there is a generic function `func` and then (humanely speaking) more specialized function `func` for classes deriving from `Base` via CRTP, which is only enabled for appropriate argument type via `enable_if`.

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

// CRTP hierarchy
template<class T> class Base{ };
class Derived: public Base<Derived>{};

// overload 1
template<class T> void func(const T& a){ std::cerr<<"1\n"; }
// overload 2
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base<T>,T>::value,int>::type* = nullptr>
inline void func(const Base<T>& obj){ std::cerr<<"2\n"; }

int main(void){ func(Derived()); }
```

The compiler still thinks, however, that the first overload is a better match. I understand that `enable_if` only enables the function but does not make it better for the overload resolution.

I am sorry to say I was not able to make much sense from [Function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) section of c++ reference.

Can anyone give an advise how to make compiler prefer the second function?

Thanks!

**Edit: MOTIVATION:** In the real use, those functions should handle various scalar and array types (Eigen, in particular, which is using CRTP). Scalars should cover all numeric types like ints, floats, ... (without enumerating them) and the other overload should cover arrays — again, without enumerating them, but knowing all of them derive from `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>`.

Comment: Is intentional that the `enable_if` condition doesn't depend on `T` at all, and is simply always `true`?

Comment: Sorry! I just fixed that, it was supposed to be `T` everywhere. Bad copy&paste. The problem remains, though.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, I changed to std::cerr output. Same issue.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the argument type is `Y` where `Y` inherits `X` which inherits `Base<X>`?

Comment: @aschepler overload 2 should be selected. I added an explanation at the end for context.

Comment: Can't you use `SFINAE` on both `overloads`? Make the first overload substitution fail when the type passed *is* a `class` derived from `base`

Comment: @eudoxos That make sthe situation much more complicated, since if passing `Y` to the template, it has no way of deducing `X` even if `Y` derives from it. You should make your question a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `constexpr` `if`s to select the correct function from a single public function.

**C++17**

```
namespace
{
    template<typename T>
    inline void base_func( const T& derived );

    template<typename T>
    inline void other_func( const T& otherType );
}

template<typename T>
inline void func( const T& type )
{ 
     if constexpr( std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>, T> )
         base_func( type );
     else
         other_func( type );
}
```

**C++14 Using traits**

```
namespace
{
    template<typename T>
    inline void base_func( const T& derived );

    template<typename T>
    inline void other_func( const T& otherType );

    template <bool B>
    struct func_select_trait;

    template <>
    struct func_select_trait<true>
    { 
      template <typename T>
      static void call( const T& derived ) { base_func<T>( derived ); }
    };

    template <>
    struct func_select_trait<false>
    {
      template <typename T>
      static void call( const T& otherType ) { other_func<T>( otherType ); }
    }; 

}

template<typename T>
inline void func( const T& type )
{ 
     func_select_trait<std::is_base_of<Base<T>, T>::value>::call<T>( type );
}
```

Comment: C++17 though (whereas OP tags C++14).

Comment: I knew the `std::is_base_of_v` was `17` but I was unsure about the `if constexpr`. Yeah just checked `cppreference` and `if constexpr` is indeed `17`.

Comment: Whereas _t/_v can simply be replaced in previous version, It is not the case for `if constexpr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 OK I gave 2 versions. One for `17` and another for `14`. The `14` version is ugly...

Answer (score 3):

The 2 overloads are viables

- overload 1. has exact match
- overload 2. has derived to base conversion

See:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences for more details

You might SFINAE the first overload:

```
// overload 1
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>, T>, int> = 0>
void func(const T& a){ std::cerr<<"1\n"; }
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9b56017940858a6)

Comment: Okay, the derived-to-base conversion can be removed by passing the arg as `const T&` rather than `const Base<T>&`. Then the match is ambiguous.

Putting SFINAE on the first overload means I have to mention all other possible overload types there, so not very elegant maintenance-wise. Someone adding support for other types of arrays later will have to update the list.

Comment: @eudoxos: You might be interested by [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061842/best-way-to-specialize-function-using-enable-if-for-only-some-types/61062536#61062536): adding *priority* to overloads.

Comment: Wow, that actually looks very nice :) Thanks!